# json is not retrieving data

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I'm new to json and I'm having problems retrieving this information i think is a cross domain issue but I can't get it to work.

PHP FILES:

```
include ('tew.php');
$converter = new Encryption;
$query="SELECT tbl_pizarra.idpizarra, tbl_pizarra.titulo, tbl_pizarra.imagenchica FROM tbl_pizarra ORDER BY idpizarra DESC LIMIT 3";
$sql=mysqli_query($tew,$query);

$datosJSON =  '{"pizarra": [';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
$datosJSON .=  '{ 
"idpizarra":"'.$converter->encode($row['idpizarra']).'", 
"titulo":"'.$row['titulo'].'",
"imagenChica":"'.$rutaImagenes.$row['imagenchica'].'"
},'; 
}
$datosJSON .= ']}';
echo $datosJSON;

include ('tew.php');
$converter = new Encryption;
$query="SELECT tbl_pizarron.idpizarron, tbl_pizarron.titulo, tbl_pizarron.imagen FROM tbl_pizarron ORDER BY idpizarron DESC LIMIT 3";
$sql=mysqli_query($tew,$query);

$datosJSON =  '{"pizarron": [';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $datosJSON .=  '{ 
    "idpizarron":"'.$converter->encode($row['idpizarron']).'", 
    "titPizarron":"'.utf8_encode($row['titulo']).'"
    },'; 
}
$datosJSON .= ']}';
echo $datosJSON;
```

JSON DATA:

```
{"pizarra": [{ "idpizarra":"xET8dKAk_F-4RlUq7brYPpGV3LvuC7pRBPm722FJQpU", "titulo":"Bienvenida y Agradecimiento casa 22", "imagenChica":"http://tuedificiowebdemo.com/images/pizarras/tew_Caminadora Suspiro 21386344709.JPG" },{ "idpizarra":"Nkblz3he-ABmNFbQNInKN89Mx6NWVar-YFqeUNjyWBM", "titulo":"proyecto Plantas", "imagenChica":"http://tuedificiowebdemo.com/images/pizarras/tew_foto1380142984.jpg" },{ "idpizarra":"ZaKIOE6yAVB8Q0YBNn13b-wdI9FYGoriIvMwumY7LdU", "titulo":"COMPRA DE LA CUBIERTA DE LA ALBERCA", "imagenChica":"http://tuedificiowebdemo.com/images/pizarras/tew_CubiertaDeAlberca21378356769.jpg" },]}

{"pizarron": [{ "idpizarron":"I0jks9aMm3znH1Mg__od5sd_buDp5H8zbisrPQkQj3o", "titPizarron":"FECHAS CORTES JARDINES" },{ "idpizarron":"dfa-LPljkeJWagSDMy5bjES3y6Drqn0EOxd568mYWy8", "titPizarron":"Cuota de Mantenimiento 2014" },{ "idpizarron":"yce4YmZ2ridNmkYr5Y1dU2TmTNI7EtdA2667F_5nEyQ", "titPizarron":"PROXIMAS FECHAS DE CORTE JARDINES" },]}
```

HTML FILE IM USING TO GET THE INFORMAITON:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://tuedificiowebdemo.com/tewMobile/php/noticiasPizarra2.php?jsoncallback=?",function(data) {
            $.each(data.pizarra, function(i,data) {
                var div_data = "<a href='documentos_detalles.html?id="+data.idpizarra+"' class='notiClick'><div><img src='images/alert.png' width=100' align='absmiddle'>"+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+data.titulo+"</div></a>";
                $(div_data).appendTo("#pizarra");
                });
            }
        );

        $.getJSON("http://tuedificiowebdemo.com/tewMobile/php/noticiasPizarron2.php?jsoncallback=?",function(data) {
            $.each(data.pizarron, function(i,data) {
            var div_data = "<a href='documentos_detalles.html?id="+data.idpizarron+"' class='notiClick'><div>"+data.titPizarron+"</div></a>";
                $(div_data).appendTo("#pizarron");
                });
            }
        );
    return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div id="pizarra"></div>
<div id="pizarron"></div>
```

ANY SUGESTION....
thanks.

Comment: Your json data is invalid...copyed and pasted on jsonlint: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: It seems that you need to get rid of the last comma `,`...btw why you are not using php BIF `json_encode` instead to hardcoding the json??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an array in PHP and use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) $json = json_encode($array) to create a string with json data.
2. You are outputting 2 independent json strings which will not be read correctly. Both getJSON will get the same double invalid json string.

Invalid like your example:

```
{/*data here*/}
{/*data here*/}
```

Valid:

```
[
    {/*data here*/},
    {/*data here*/}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a cross domain issue...include this header in the php page

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```